# how to use --label-filter with external-dns to filter the ingress in kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, bitnami, external-dns

I had many dns records in my dns-zone in azure and i need to use External-dns to automate dns record creation/deletion but i need to filter by labels whene external-dns found other label in the aks ingrees than this one below he musn't touch it :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sample-rule
  labels:
    ingress: externaldns
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    ingress: "externaldns"
```

the Helm command :

```
helm install external-dns-frontend-sint bitnami/external-dns \                                                                                                                      
    --wait \
    --namespace externaldns \
    --set txtOwnerId=az-frontend-aks\
    --set provider=azure \
    --set azure.resourceGroup=az-tools \
    --set txtOwnerId=az-frontend-ak \
    --set azure.tenantId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \
    --set azure.subscriptionId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \
    --set azure.aadClientId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \
    --set azure.aadClientSecret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \
    --set azure.cloud=AzurePublicCloud \
    --set policy=sync \
    --set labelfilter=”ingre=externaldns” \
    --set annotationfilter=”ingress=externaldns” \
    --set domainFilters={azdns.test.com}
```

i need to know how can i use this argument with Bitnami/external-dns chart to activate the label filter please.
any help please

Last : the filter doesn't work he created all record from the ingress in the same namespace

Answer (score 4):

•   You can use the label filter command with bitnami external dns charts as below to filter out the labels which are not passed as aks ingress in external dns.

```
‘ $helm install my-release -f values.yaml bitnami/external-dns ‘
```

In the values.yaml file, specify the label filter and annotation filter parameters as below: -

```
 labelfilter: “ingress: ‘externaldns’”
 annotationfilter: “ingress: ‘externaldns’”
```

OR

```
‘ $helm install my-release \
  --set-labelfilter=”ingress=externaldns” \
  --set-annotationfilter=”ingress=externaldns” \
   bitnami/external-dns ’
```

Also, please take into consideration that ‘annotation filter’ filters sources managed by external-dns via annotation using label selector while the ‘label filter’ only selects sources managed by external-dns using the label selector. Thus, filtering based on annotation means that the external-dns controller will receive all resources of that kind and then filter on the client-side. In larger clusters with many resources which change frequently this can cause performance issues. If only some resources need to be managed by an instance of external-dns then label filtering can be used instead of annotation filtering. This means that only those resources which match the selector specified in ‘--label-filter’ will be passed to the controller.

Please find the below links for reference: -

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/faq.md#running-an-internal-and-external-dns-service

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/external-dns/#external-dns-parameters

Comment: i use this Helm cmd but the external dns dosn't filter by the label filter i must use the annotation filter also  ?
Helm install external-dns-frontend-sint bitnami/external-dns \                                                                                                                      
   .
   .
   .
 --set labelfilter=”ingre=externaldns” \
    --set domainFilters={azdns.test.com}

with this configuration the external dns create all records without verifying the filter

Comment: Yes, I would suggest you to use annotation filter along with label filter to narrow down the actual dns records to be filtered out. Also, you can try the zone name filter and zone ID filter along with it to be specific about the dns records coming from to filter out. Please refer to this link for more detailed example - https://docs.syseleven.de/metakube/en/tutorials/use-external-dns

Comment: the filter doesn't work i updated my question

Answer (score 0):

there was two issues :

1. mistake in the annotation filter, filter must be in capital letter

   annotationFilter: “ingress: externaldns”
2. The label filter is a new feature must be used in the new Helm chart version 5.5.1